# How to implement a calendar in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

I have a web application that uses HTML and Javascript. I want to create a textbox that allows to user to enter in a keyword and submit it. I also want a little calendar icon next to the textbox so the user can click on it to popup a calendar to select a date as the keyword, and then submit that.

I have tried to implement Jcalendar and DatePicker but couldn't get either one working.

Is there something that I can use that will meet my needs? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is [jQuery's Date Picker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).  One line of code....done.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQueryUI datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

Try the jquery ui datepicker

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

Something a bit like this?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Hey is it enough to just add these

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">`

in the head section of the application?

or should we download the plugin into our project? which I feel will be safer considering the site may not stay for ever :)

please guide me

Comment: @Reddy, I would download the scripts, host them myself and link to them that way. However, I would make an exception for jQuery, as there are some advantages to using a CDN instead (e.g. a user may already have a copy of jQuery from a CDN in their cache, and when you use the CDN hosted script their browser won't need to re-download it, resulting in a performance boost), please see this link for more details: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jQuery UI's calendar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger) with an icon-trigger.

To have an icon trigger the calender, it would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#idOfYourInput" ).datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-calendar-date-pickers.html

Number 10 looks like what you need:
http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-date-range-picker/full_screen_preview/261519?ref=themespotters&ref=themespotters&clickthrough_id=42454046&redirect_back=true